# CoreLocation - but for indoors (Swift 2 / IOS)

Tags: gps, swift2, cllocationmanager

I am working on Proof of Concept functionality for an app. This app will be used **primarily indoors**. The intended result is being able to track if a user traveled more than 3 meters indoors after pressing a button. I have this working using CoreLocation - but the results are not cutting it. The numbers "jump" around sometimes, which would deem this app useless.

I am looking for any possible alternatives. Looked into the accelerameter and pedamater as well, but still feel like GPS / CoreLocation is my best bet. *(Or is it...?)*

One thing I was thinking of is using requestLocation, and re-checking it every 10 seconds to see if the phone traveled more than 3 meters. It does not need to be real-time, so I am okay with a 10 second buffer. Would this be the best approach? (downside to this is requestLocation is introduced in ios9... would need alternate solution for ios8 and below)

**Here is my code (that produces the GPS "jumping") :**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]


    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
    }

    let distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance = latestLocation.distanceFromLocation(startLocation)

    distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", distanceBetween)

    if distanceBetween > 3.0{
        labelOutput.text = "you traveled more than 3 meters"
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Here is a good article about indoor positioning in ios 8.  Looks like there are many factors that effect the reliability http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/05/ios-8-indoor-positioning-m7/ 
Here is the wwdc video about it https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/708/

Answer (score 1):

GPS positioning is accomplished by processing GPS signal in L1 and L2 frequencies (extra L3 for newer GPS satellites). The signal that leave GPS is received by a GPS receiver after passing through ionosphere and troposphere which contribute to distort the signal. The total distance traveled by GPS signal (with error) is measured and your position is computed based on the measurement. A lot of techniques have been developed to mitigate the iono and tropo errors. But f you are inside of building, the GPS signal will have serious amount of multipath error which is very difficult to deal with. I would say for indoor application, you may want to consider combining other sensors as well not just GPS.

Comment: "you may want to consider combining other sensors as well" - do you mean the pedometer / accelerameter?

Comment: http://www.theverge.com/2013/2/13/3985108/research-finds-gps-improved-with-accelerometers-gyroscopes